# How to compensate for status bar in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-relativelayout

I am new to android development. I am making a UI for my android app. Now, mdpi screen's height is 480px. So I designed my UI to have a height of 480px on mdpi's screens. But because the status bar takes some space at the top of the devices, some of my ImageViews in RelativeLayout are overlapping. How to compensate for the space the status bar takes? Because for different screens, the status bar will be of different sizes and in tablets the status bar might not even be at the top. I am confused, help!

EDIT: The XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/volbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/base" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/head" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:text="@string/press_to_update" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/frag1"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Relativelayout , you have used match_parent / wrap_content. So it will fit to the screen. But you have specified that you have designed the ui for 480px on mdpi's screens.
Since it is not clear how you designed the ui to 480px on mdpi screen. I guess , might have used drawables used in Image View which fits the 480 px for mdpi screens. 
drawables should be placed in the ratio of 3:4:6:8

for example

lpdi:mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi = 3:4:6:8

for example if you keep an image for mdpi as 40px
Then,for  ldpi  = 30 px , hdpi = 60px , xhdpi = 80px.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Supporting Multiple Screens Best Practices](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence), you should design your layouts to expand or contract to fill the space available. On a phone, the most important part is making sure your content fits horizontally and (if needed) scrolls vertically. You can add a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) if you need to fit more vertical content in a layout than your device has room.

Comment: It is a music player's UI so can't use scrolling.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I read that link you gave, it says that the drawables rescale themselves according to the screen size, but mine are not scaling up on bigger screens!

Comment: @vergilcorleone maybe you have to create more layout for different screen size, like sw600dp for 7" tablet or sw720dp for 10" tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to set the height to a specific size. Use "wrap_content" or "match_parent" as the value for "layout_height" whenever possible.

If you feel like the content will be taller than the available screen height you will want to use a ScrollView as the container for the content.

If you feel like the content will always fit in the available screen height then you can simply use a container (like a RelativeLayout) with layout_height="match_parent".

If you have a specific layout you need help with you could post the XML.

Comment: It is a music player's play screen, so scrolling is not ok. I am using RelativelLayout with layout_height=match_parent, but like I said the ImageViews are overlapping. I'll post the XML above..

Comment: OK, yes, the reason they are overlapping is because you have not told the RelativeLayout how the ImageViews should be laid out relative to each other. If you want imageView4 to be below imageView2 then you need to set android:layout_below="@id/imageView2" on imageView4. All the children of the RelativeLayout need such constraints otherwise they can potentially overlap.

Comment: I did what you said, still overlap is there. I added android:layout_below="@id/imageView2 to imageView 4, still the overlap is there!

Answer (score 0):

As other users suggested, you should not hard code the specific heights but use `wrap_content` or `match_parent`.

If you still want to follow this way, why don't you reduce the height of your RelativeLayout by the dimension of the ActionBar? In Android 4.0+ the default height is `48dip`, in landscape is `40dp`, in sw600dp is `56dp`. You can also get height programmatically calling `getActionBar().getHeight()` in your activity. For more infos about ActionBar appearance, see [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#GeneralStyles).

Comment: I designed the 'drawable' elements in Adobe Illustrator, so obviously needed to hardcode.